# Magento installation issue windows 7 / wamp 2.2

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I have wamp 2.2 installed on my windows 7, which has php 5.3.10.

I am trying to install magento 1.7.0.2 and getting following error.

when accessing like 127.0.0.1/magento/

> The connection was reset

when accessing like localhost/magento/

it redirects me to http://www.localhost.com/magento/ and says

> ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Magento on Wamp is a bit of a pain. I would recommend giving ampps a go: http://www.ampps.com/

Comment: Not so, magento installs perfectly well.

Comment: It's probably fixed in a update. I always had issues with curl not being included by default.

Comment: Ok but with wamp that should just be a click on the PHP menu to include the curl extension

Comment: It wasn't when I used it, if you google wamp curl extension I wasn't the only one. Anyway, I don't think this discussion is relevant to this question. I just found ampps easier to use, creating domains is easy as pie in ampps.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to install complex applications like Magento into a Named Virtual Host.

If you have never done that with Apache before here is a quick [tutorial/HowTo](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113853,113854#msg-113854)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install magento on windows

1. Download and install wamp server. Link - http://www.wampserver.com/en/
2. Download Magento. Link - https://www.magentocommerce.com/download, select   the .zip format for windows.
3. Unzip the magento into the path c:/wamp/www/
4. Add the line 127.0.0.1 www.yourdomain.com to the host.ics file in c:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/, where 127.0.0.1 refers to the localhost.
5. Create an empty database in using phpMyAdmin.
6. Now open your browser and run the link www.yourdomain.com which will open the magento installation wizard.
7. Complete the installation

Answer (score -1):

I got its answer after consulting one of my friend.

It can be done with a small trick

go to

C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router

folder

open Admin.php
and  find  _shouldBeSecure function and redefine

like

> protected function _shouldBeSecure($path)
>
> {
>
> ```
>   return ; // ie return false, say no to secure path as your localhost
> ```
>
> does not need it. }

Now try to install your magento. It will work like charm .

Comment: For instance, I didn't downvote you, I didn't even read your solution.